# Share option: How to append into text file?

Tags: file-management, share-menu, text-editor

If I go to share in any app or from selected text (icon with three connected dots), I get some sharing options such as SMS, Bluetooth, WiFi direct, etc.

But I would also like to dump it directly into a chosen text file destination such as /*(the default Android user directory path, different by each version*)/Documents/Shared.txt

I need this for easily storing URLs into a file **without needing to fumble and fiddle around with copying the URL bar and pasting it into a text editor,** which costs a lot of time. The browser usually has a *Share* option.

Additionally, I would like it to be **appended** to the text file, not overwritten.
I am also fine if a new file is created each time, because some desktop PC commands can easily put 1000 tiny text files into 1 file, and Notepad++ and some Linux commands also support searching all files in a directory for text, even with regular expressions.

Comment: Many file managers such as Solid File Explorer, ES File Manager, etc., provide option to save the selected content / page into a text file. You can find "Save to" or something similar with their icon in the Share menu. Have you tried them yet? They may both overwrite as well as create a new file.

Comment: Thank you, @FireLord. I already knew that, but thanks for reminding me. +1. It needs a few additional taps, and everything into one file is more preferrable, but as already said, I can do that on the desktop PC. So thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Simpletask does what you ask for. It creates a new line in a todo.txt file.

Personally, I use [Simpletask Cloudless](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.mpcjanssen.simpletask) and sync with syncthing. There is also [Simpletask Nextcloud](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.mpcjanssen.simpletask.nextcloud) and [Simpletask Dropbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.mpcjanssen.todotxtholo). And if you like it, we should [donate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.mpcjanssen.simpletask.donate) to the author (just found this amazing solution two days ago, so I didn't do it yet).

Comment: I've already heard of TodoTxt. So this is it's successor. Thanks, looks interesting.

Comment: I tried it out myself and it works fine. Only issue I have is that it just automatically appends the content to the todo list, without letting me enter some additional context for whatever I'm sharing. Does anyone know if there is a setting for that? It would be nice if it would work similarly to how Google Keep does it, as they let a window appear for you to type into before you share the link.